# Flutter - Keep scroll of SingleChildScrollView with AnimatedSize

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-animation

I have a scroll problem for a SingleChildScrollView element.
My view is composed as follows:
A picture,
A SingleChildScrollView (Elem list 2, 3,4, in the picture),
An AnimatedSize widget that contains either a list or nothing.
By default my AnimatedSize widget does not contain anything and is not visible like that :

[image]

And when it updates to contain a list, the scroll of my SingleChildScrollView is shifted.
Like that :
[image]

I would like the scroll to stay at the end like that:

[image]

I know I can trigger an event to automatically scroll to the end, but it's not smooth. I think there is a better solution. Hoping to find an answer here
Here is my code:

```
Column(
          children: [
            SizedBox(
              height: 200,
              child: ClipRRect(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                child: Image.asset(
                  imagePath,
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                controller: scrollController,
                physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                child: Column(
                    children:[
                      ...listInterractionShow.map((e) => e.getWidget(context)).toList(),
                    ]
                ),
              ),
            ),
            AnimatedSize(
                curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
                duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 100),
                child:
                currentChoix == null? Container()
                    :Container(
                  decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(top: Radius.circular(20)),
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                  child: Column(
                      children: listChildren()
                  ),
                )
            )
          ],
        ),
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can play with the flexible and expanded giving them a greater flex than the one you want to show larger on the screen